# Category Page Script

Tags: html, css

I have a View Post page that displays all of the posts on my site, but I was hoping for a way to categorize them. Weather by topic title or actual categories, I would just like to have them a little bit separated. I have almost no idea where to begin. Help?

Comment: @peter As I said, I have almost no idea where to begin.

Comment: Oh dear, then you have misunderstood how Stack works. You show us broken code or what you have already tried and we attempt to help out, we don't write the code for you...

Comment: @PeteR I didn't need it written for me... what I need is an idea of what I need to do for the categories. I need to know what I should do with tables and such, what should I pull from a table, what should I leave there, should the categories be in the same table as the posts(no, they should not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="category">Category</h3>
<div class="sub">
    <a href="#">val 1</a>
    <a href="#">val 2</a>
    <a href="#">val 3</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.category { font-weight:bold; margin:10px 0 0 0; }
.sub { margin-left:16px; display:none; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".category").click(function(){

    if (!$(this).next('.sub').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next('.sub').show();
    } else {
        $(this).next(".sub").hide();   
    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qFK3x/3/)

Comment: I could probably make that work, But i meant like the category is a link and when you click that it shows the posts

Comment: I'll look at it... thanks... you wouldnt by any chance be willing to help someone out on the side a little... would you?

Comment: @user2544765 Feel free to contact me on my email-address, you can find it on my profile.

Comment: @user2544765 if my answer helped you, make sure to upvote or mark as accepted! :)